# Java: Am having trouble matching item(s) from ArrayList using Optional Request Params with HTTP GET

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, arraylist

Using Java 1.8 & Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE.

My requirements are to create a HTTP GET endpoint which takes a query string with optional request parameters:

```
HTTP GET /groups/query[?name=<nq>][&gid=<gq>][&member=<mq1>[&member=<mq2>][&.
..]]
```

Need to return a list of groups matching all of the specified query fields. The bracket notation indicates that any of the following query parameters may be supplied:

- name
- gid
- member (repeated)

Any group containing all the specified members should be returned, i.e. when query members are a subset of group members.

```
Example Query: GET /groups/query?member=_analyticsd&member=_networkd
```

Example Response:

```
[
  {
    “name”: “_analyticsusers”,
    “gid”: 250,
    “members”: [“_analyticsd’, ”_networkd”, ”_timed”]
  }
]
```

---

RestController:

```
@RestController
public class GroupController {

    @Autowired
    GroupService groupService;
    private HttpHeaders headers = null;

    @Autowired
    public GroupController() {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/groups/query" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "APPLICATION/JSON")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getGroupsBasedOnRequestParams(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name, 
                                                           @RequestParam(value = "gid", required = false) Integer gid,
                                                           @RequestParam(value ="member", required = false) String member) {

        List<Group> groups = groupService.findUsingRequestParams("/etc/group", name, gid, member);

        if (groups == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(groups, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Group:

```
public class Group {
    private Integer gid;
    private String name;
    private List<String> members;

    public Group(String line) {
        String[] items = line.split(":");

        this.name = items[0];
        this.gid = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);

        if (items.length > 3){
            this.members = Arrays.asList(items[3]);
        }
    }
```

GroupServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class GroupServiceImpl implements GroupService {

    @Override
    public List<Group> findUsingRequestParams(String line, String name, Integer gid, String member) {
        List<Group> allGroups = FileParserUtils.parseFileForGroups(line);
        List<Group> matchedGroups = new ArrayList<>();

        // this works for name and gid
        for (Group group : allGroups) {
            if (group.getName().equals(name) || group.getGid() == gid) {
                matchedGroups.add(group);
            }
        }

        return matchedGroups;
    }
```

But when checking String member it doesn't work:

```
    for (Group group : allGroups) {
        if (group.getName().equals(name) || group.getGid() == gid || group.getMembers().contains(member)) {
            matchedGroups.add(group);
        }
    }
```

---

This causes a NPE:

```
2019-03-25 05:43:42,695 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/MyService] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.myapp.service.GroupServiceImpl.findUsingRequestParams(GroupServiceImpl.java:33)
    at com.myapp.controller.GroupController.getGroupsBasedOnRequestParams(GroupController.java:72)
```

---

Question(s):

Why does this work:

```
for (Group group : allGroups) {
    if (group.getName().equals(name) || group.getGid() == gid) {
        matchedGroups.add(group);
    }
}
```

But not this (this causes the NullPointerException):

```
for (Group group : allGroups) {
    if (group.getName().equals(name) || group.getGid() == gid || group.getMembers().contains(member)) {
        matchedGroups.add(group);
    }
}
```

---

Also, how can I return the entire group when using only a subset inside my members?

Example Query:

```
GET /groups/query?member=_analyticsd&member=_networkd
```

Example Response:

```
[
  {
    “name”: “_analyticsusers”,
    “gid”: 250,
    “members”: [“_analyticsd’, ”_networkd”, ”_timed”]
  }
]
```

---

Also, how can I set it up so the members are repeated in my GroupController?

```
GET /groups/query?member=_analyticsd&member=_networkd&member=_timed
```

Comment: Check if `group.getMembers()` is null?

Comment: `ArrayList.contains(foo)` will thrown a `NullPointerException` if `foo` is null.  In your case, you need to verify that `member` is not null before calling `group.getMembers().contains(member)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Group Constructor is wrong:

```
public class Group {

    private Integer gid;
    private String name;
    private List<String> members;

    public Group(String line) {
        String[] items = line.split(":");

        this.name = items[0];
        this.gid = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);
        this.members = new ArrayList<>(items.length - 3);

        for (int i = 3; i < items.length; i++) {
            this.members.add(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than changing my Group constructor to what @codeflush.dev suggested, I changed the implementation inside:

```
@Override
public List<Group> findUsingRequestParams(String line, String name, Integer gid, String member) {
    List<Group> allGroups = FileParserUtils.parseFileForGroups(line);
    List<Group> matchedGroups = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Group group : allGroups) {
        if (group.getMembers() != null) {
            if (group.getName().equals(name) || group.getGid() == gid || group.getMembers().contains(member)) {
                matchedGroups.add(group);
            }
        }
    }
    return matchedGroups;
}
```

Looks like its working now.